# Solution verification: Prove $\int_A f= \underline{\int_Q} (f_+)_A -\underline{\int_Q}(f_-)_A$

Tags: integration, analysis

This problem is from Munkres's analysis of manifold 15.7

The question is the following
[image]

Some clarifications:
$\displaystyle \int_A f$ is extended integration, and this is defined as $\int_A f= \sup_D \int_D f$ where $D$ is any compact and rectifiable set in $A$

And since $A$ is open and bounded, $f$ is bounded, $\int_A f$ exists. This is proved in the book

My attempt:

I think it is enough to only prove this when function $f$ is nonnegative.

That is, I only need to show $$\int_A f = \underline{\int_Q} f_A $$

First, I will show $$\underline{\int_Q} f_A \le \int_A f $$

Consider a partition $P$ for $Q$, then the lower sum of $f_A$ is $$ \sum_{i=1}^k \inf_{i} f_A(x) v(I_i)$$

Then, for each small rectangle $I_i$, if it is not totally contained in $A$, then by the definition of $f_A$, $\inf_i f_A(x)=0$. Thus, the lower sum can be rewritten as $$ \sum_{I_j\in\{I_i\}} \inf_j f_A(x) v(I_j)$$

where each $I_j\subset A$

Then, since on each $I_j$, $\inf_j f_A(x)\cdot v(I_j)\le \int_{I_j} f_A$ (this makes sense since rectangles are compact and rectifiable, the ordinary integral $\int_{I_j} f_A$ should exist)
we have $$\sum_{I_j\in \{I_i\}} \inf f_j(x) v(I_j)\le \sum_{I_j\in \{I_i\}} \int_{I_j} f_A$$
By the property of ordinary integration, $\displaystyle \sum_{I_j\in\{I_i\}} \int_{I_j} f_A=\int_D f_A $ where $D$ is the finite union of the small rectangles $I_j$, so it is rectifiable and compact.

Thus, we have $$ \sum_{i=1}^k \inf_{i} f_A(x) v(I_i)\le \int_D f_A $$. Let $\|P\|\to \infty$ , we have $\displaystyle \underline{\int_{Q}} f_A \le \sup_D \int_D f =\int_A f $

Next, I will show $ \displaystyle \int_A f \le \underline{\int_Q} f_A $

Consider any compact and rectifiable set $D\subset A$, we have $ \displaystyle \int_D f =\int_D f_A $

Then, since for any open set, there exists a collection of compact and rectifiable sets $\{C_n\}$ such that $\bigcup_{n} C_n =A, \  C_n\subset int(C_{n+1})$(This is proved in the book), there exists a $n$ large enough such that $D\subset int(C_n)$

Then, since $D$ is compact, and $int(C_n)$ is open, there can exist a finite collection of rectangles $\{J_k\}$ such that $$D\subset \bigcup_{k}int(J_k) \subset \bigcup_{k}J_k\subset int(C_n)$$

Let $J=\bigcup_{k}J_k$, then we consider the ordinary integration on $\displaystyle \int_J f_A$. This integration makes sense since $J\subset A$ and $J$ is compact and rectifiable. Then since $f_A\ge 0$ and $D\subset J$, the inequality $\displaystyle  \int_D f \le \int_J f =\int_J f_A$ holds

And we have $\displaystyle \int_J f_A = \underline{\int_J} f_A$ since the integration exists

Finally, since $f_A\ge 0$ and $J\subset Q$, the inequality $$ \underline{\int_J} f_A\le \underline{\int_Q} f_A $$ holds

Thus, since $D$ is arbitrary, we have $$\int_A f = \sup_D \int_D f \le \underline{\int_Q} f_A $$

By two inequalities, the question is proved.

Is my proof okay or not?  Thank you for checking this! (Also thanks for reading, my proof is quite long...)